# How would I copy an Excel sheet that has formulas with "Table2[Date].." to a new sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, spreadsheet, copy

I created a sheet that uses several tables. There are many formulas that reference different rows of different tables on the same sheet. The sheet was for the month of Feb. I want to copy the format of the sheet (empty) to other sheets successively titled with each month. The problem I have is that when I copy the sheet to a new sheet, my formulas that reference a table no longer work. I need to copy the sheet and automatically adjust the "Table2[Date]..." so that the refrence automatically refrences the equivalent table on the new sheet... I don't know if I am making any sense.

Ill explain it a different way just in case,

So, for instance, I have a "Units Tested" table on Feb sheet, this would be Table2. I copy the sheet to March sheet, the formulas that reference Table2 no longer work. The "Units Tested" table for March is not Table2 (I have no idea what it becomes). I either need the March "Units Tested" table to become Table2 so that the copied formulas work, or I need the formulas to automatically update so they reference the "Units Tested" table for March.

Comment: This is so confusing. I gave up after reading the question like 20 times. Can't help until you make it clearer using screenshots or adding more clarity to the question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just want to copy the structure of the entire workbook, you don't want to keep the original data, you just want to save the original formula used between each table and the cells.（***According to your description, so far your original workbook has not filled any data, just created a few empty tables and then referenced the formula***）

This allows you to build your next month's report without having to restructure your workbook each time.

You can copy and paste a table with a reference formula, click "Data" - "Edit Link" - "Change Source" to select the current workbook storage location. Formulas with links automatically reference the new data source in this table.

If my understanding is not correct, please feel free to correct me.